# Calculate distance from one point to all others

Tags: python, proximity

I am working with a list of ID, X, and Y data for fire hydrant locations. I am trying to find the three closest fire hydrants for each fire hydrant in the list.

a = [[ID, X, Y],[ID, X, Y]]

I have tried implementing this using a for loop but I am having trouble because I cannot keep the original point data the same while iterating through the list of points.

Is there a strait forward way to calculate the distance from one point to each of the other points and iterate this for each point in the list? I am very new to python and have not seen anything about how to do this online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding dummy data, what you tried, and expected results  to your question would help ;)

Comment: Welcome James...if you can post in the for loop you have and also an example of the issue you mention.  With as little as just a few example points I am sure someone will have an answer you need.  There are many powerful python packages that are perfectly suited for this, but a little more detail from you and folks will be able to get you set up better.  For example [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) has a function that automatically calculates distance metrics for coordinate pairs.

Comment: I think you can have a for loop inside your main for loop to solve your problem. Points in the first loop can be preserved as your main point and the second loop are the ones you want to find distance.

Comment: Do you wan't to calculate the distance from one point to all others, or do you wan't to find the three closest fire hydrants for each fire hydrant? For the second case it isn't necessary to calculate all the distances, just use a kd-tree https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to calculate all distances of all points to all others to get the three nearest neighbours for all points.

A [kd-tree search](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) will be much more efficient due to its O(log n) complexity instead of a O(n**2) time complexity for the brute force method (calculating all distances).

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

#Create some coordinates and indices
#It is assumed that the coordinates are unique (only one entry per hydrant)
Coords=np.random.rand(1000*2).reshape(1000,2)
Coords*=100
Indices=np.arange(1000) #Indices 

def get_indices_of_nearest_neighbours(Coords,Indices):
  tree=spatial.cKDTree(Coords)
  #k=4 because the first entry is the nearest neighbour 
  # of a point with itself
  res=tree.query(Coords, k=4)[1][:,1:]
  return Indices[res]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Let's say you have an input list with this format `[[ID, X, Y],[ID, X, Y]]`.

You can simply loop through each hydrant when looping through each hydrant and calculate the min distance between them. You just need to have some variable to store the min distance for each hydrant and the ID of the closest hydrant.

```
import math # for sqrt calculation


def distance(p0, p1):
    """ Calculate the distance between two hydrant """
    return math.sqrt((p0[1] - p1[1])**2 + (p0[2] - p1[2])**2)


input = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, -3], [2, -3, 5]] # your input list of hydrant

for current_hydrant in input:  # loop through each hydrant
    min_distance = 999999999999999999999999
    closest_hydrant = 0
    for other_hydrant in input:  # loop through each other hydrant
        if current_hydrant != other_hydrant:
            curr_distance = distance(current_hydrant, other_hydrant) # call the distance function
            if curr_distance < min_distance: # find the closet hydrant
                min_distance = curr_distance
                closest_hydrant = other_hydrant[0]
    print("Closest fire hydrants to the", current_hydrant[0], "is the hydrants",
          closest_hydrant, "with the distance of", min_distance)  # print the closet hydrant
```

Since the distance function is not very complicated i rewrite it, you can use some other function in scipy or numpy library to get the distance.

Hope this can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have geolocation, we can perform simple distance calculation(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to get kilometers distance between two locations. This code is NOT meant to be efficient. If this is what you want we can use numpy to speed it up:

```
import math

def distance(lat,lon, lat2,lon2):

    R = 6372.8  # Earth radius in kilometers

    # change lat and lon to radians to find diff

    rlat = math.radians(lat)
    rlat2 = math.radians(lat2)
    rlon = math.radians(lon)
    rlon2 = math.radians(lon2)

    dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2 - lon)


    m = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + \
        math.cos(rlat)*math.cos(rlat2)*math.sin(dlon/2)**2

    return 2 * R * math.atan2(math.sqrt(m),
                               math.sqrt(1 - m))

a = [['ID1', 52.5170365, 13.3888599],
     ['ID2', 54.5890365, 12.5865499],
     ['ID3', 50.5170365, 10.3888599],
    ]

b = []  
for id, lat, lon in a:
    for id2, lat2, lon2 in a:
        if id != id2:
            d = distance(lat,lon,lat2,lon2)
            b.append([id,id2,d])

print(b)
```