# Find common elements in subarrays of arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy arrays of shape arr1=(~140000, 3) and arr2=(~450000, 10). The first 3 elements of each row, for both the arrays, are coordinates (z,y,x). I want to find the rows of arr2 that have the same coordinates of arr1 (which can be considered a subgroup of arr2).

for example:

```
arr1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,5],[1,7,8],[5,6,7]]

arr2 = [[1,2,3,7,66,4,3,44,8,9],[1,3,9,6,7,8,3,4,5,2],[1,5,8,68,7,8,13,4,53,2],[5,6,7,6,67,8,63,4,5,20], ...]
```

I want to find common coordinates (same first 3 elements):

```
list_arr = [[1,2,3,7,66,4,3,44,8,9], [5,6,7,6,67,8,63,4,5,20], ...]
```

At the moment I'm doing this double loop, which is extremely slow:

```
list_arr=[]
for i in arr1:
    for j in arr2:
        if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and i[2]==j[2]:
            list_arr.append (j)
```

I also tried to create (after the 1st loop) a subarray of arr2, filtering it on the value of i[0] (arr2_filt = [el for el in arr2 if el[0]==i[0]). This speed a bit the operation, but it still remains really slow.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample input along with your expected outcome?! Makes it easier to help.

Comment: I've added an example, you can check it.

Comment: You can do this quite the same like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062049/4045774, but you are creating the tree with arr2[:,0:3] and check against arr1. This can be also beneficial if the points in arr2 are not exactly, but within a small tolerance the same.

Answer (score 3):

#### Approach #1

Here's a vectorized one with `views` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

a,b = view1D(arr1,arr2[:,:3])
out = arr2[np.in1d(b,a)]
```

#### Approach #2

Another with `dimensionality-reduction` for ints -

```
d = np.maximum(arr2[:,:3].max(0),arr1.max(0))
s = np.r_[1,d[:-1].cumprod()]
a,b = arr1.dot(s),arr2[:,:3].dot(s)
out = arr2[np.in1d(b,a)]
```

**Improvement #1**

We could use `np.searchsorted` to replace `np.in1d` for both of the approaches listed earlier -

```
unq_a = np.unique(a)
idx = np.searchsorted(unq_a,b)
idx[idx==len(a)] = 0
out = arr2[unq_a[idx] == b]
```

**Improvement #2**

For the last improvement on using `np.searchsorted` that also uses `np.unique`, we could use `argsort` instead -

```
sidx = a.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(a,b,sorter=sidx)
idx[idx==len(a)] = 0
out = arr2[a[sidx[idx]]==b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of `set`

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
arr2 = np.array([[7,8,9,11,14,34],[23,12,11,10,12,13],[1,2,3,4,5,6]])

# create array from arr2 with only first 3 columns
temp = [i[:3] for i in arr2]

aset = set([tuple(x) for x in arr])
bset = set([tuple(x) for x in temp])
np.array([x for x in aset & bset])
```

Output

```
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

**Edit**

Use `list comprehension`

```
l = [list(i) for i in arr2 if i[:3] in arr]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[7, 8, 9, 11, 14, 34], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: The output should be the row of arr2 (to append to a list) with all the other information, not only the coordinates. Since arr1 is a subgroup (of the coordinate of interest) of arr2, there is no point in doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it doesn't work with this. It returns all the rows where it founds even 1 of the values present in "i" (and so the other 2 are wrong).

Answer (score 0):

For integers Divakar already gave an excellent answer. If you want to compare floats you have to consider e.g. the following:

```
1.+1e-15==1.
False
1.+1e-16==1.
True
```

If this behaviour could lead to problems in your code I would recommend to perform a nearest neighbour search and probably check if the distances are within a specified threshold.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
def get_indices_of_nearest_neighbours(arr1,arr2):
  tree=spatial.cKDTree(arr2[:,0:3])
  #You can check here if the distance is small enough and otherwise raise an error
  dist,ind=tree.query(arr1, k=1)
  return ind
```