# Better way to compute Top N closest cities in Python/Numba using GPU

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba, cupy

I have M~200k points with X,Y coordinates of cities packed in a Mx2 numpy array.
Intent is, for each city to compute Top N closest cities and return their indices and distances to that city in a MxN numpy matrix.
Numba does a great job speeding up my serial python code on CPU and making it multithreaded using **prange** generator, such that on a 16 cores SSE 4.2/AVX machine call to compute 30 closest cities completes in 6min 26s while saturating all the cores:

```
@numba.njit(fastmath=True)#
def get_closest(n,N_CLOSEST,coords,i):
    dist=np.empty(n,np.float32)
    for j in range(n):
        dist[j]=(coords[i,0]-coords[j,0])**2+(coords[i,1]-coords[j,1])**2
    indices=np.argsort(dist)[1:N_CLOSEST+1]
    return indices,dist[indices]

@numba.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def get_top_T_closest_cities(coords,T):
    n=len(coords)

    N_CLOSEST=min(T,n-1)

    closest_distances=np.empty((n,N_CLOSEST),np.float32)
    closest_cities=np.empty((n,N_CLOSEST),np.int32)

    for i in prange(n):
        closest_cities[i,:],closest_distances[i,:]=get_closest(n,N_CLOSEST,coords,i)
    return closest_cities,closest_distances

closest_cities,closest_distances=get_top_T_closest_cities(data,30)
```

*Note: I wanted to use 
    mrange=np.arange(N_CLOSEST)
and 
    indices=np.argpartition(dist,mrange)
later to save some cycles, but unfortunately Numba did not support np.argpartition yet.*

Then I decided to put my newly bought RTX 2070 to some good use and try offloading these very parallel by the nature computations to the GPU, using again Numba and possibly CuPy.

After some thinking I came up with a relatively dumb rewrite, where GPU kernel handling one city at time was called consecutively for each of M cities. In that kernel, each GPU thread was computing its distance and saving to specific location in dist array. All arrays were allocated on device to minimize PCI data transfer:

```
import cupy as cp
def get_top_T_closest_cities_gpu(coords,T):
    n=len(coords)

    N_CLOSEST=min(T,n-1)

    closest_distances=cp.empty((n,N_CLOSEST),cp.float32)
    closest_cities=cp.empty((n,N_CLOSEST),cp.int32)
    device_coords=cp.asarray(coords)
    dist=cp.ndarray(n,cp.float32)
    for i in range(n):
        if (i % 1000)==0:
            print(i)
        closest_cities[i,:],closest_distances[i,:]=get_closest(n,N_CLOSEST,device_coords,i,dist)
    return cp.asnumpy(closest_cities),cp.asnumpy(closest_distances)
@cuda.jit()
def get_distances(coords,i,n,dist):
    stride = cuda.gridsize(1)
    start = cuda.grid(1)    
    for j in range(start, n, stride):
        dist[j]=(coords[i,0]-coords[j,0])**2+(coords[i,1]-coords[j,1])**2
def get_closest(n,N_CLOSEST,coords,i,dist):    
    get_distances[512,512](coords,i,n,dist)
    indices=cp.argsort(dist)[1:N_CLOSEST+1]
    return indices,dist[indices]
```

Now, computing results on GPU took almost the same 6 mins time, but GPU load was barely 1% (yes I made sure results returned by CPU and GPU versions are the same). I played a bit with block size, did not see any significant change. Interestingly, **cp.argsort** and **get_distances** were consuming approximately the same share of processing time.

I feel like it has something to do with streams, how to properly init a lot of them? This would be most straightforward way to reuse my code, by treating not 1 city at time but let's say 16 or whatever my compute capability allows, ideally 1000 maybe.

**What would those of you guys experienced in GPU coding in Numba/CuPy recommend to fully exploit power of GPU in my case?**

**Advice from pure C++ CUDA apologists would also be very welcome, as I haven't seen comparison of native Cuda solution with Numba/CuPy CUDA solution.**

*Python version: ['3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc']
platform: AMD64
system: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
Numba version: 0.41.0*

Comment: Thank you Robert for your feedback. Maybe I should rephrase Best->Better. I ended up batching multiple calls to get_distances which, on GTX 1050Ti mobile, reduced time spent on distances calculations from 2mins to 8 seconds. Cupy's argsort can't be batched evidently so whole computation takes 2 min 30s now. RTX 2070 is temporarily unavailable so will test on it later this week. Could you please post your C++ code somewhere and provide a link? It would be very useful for me to benchmark it...

Comment: Calculating all the distances is the wrong algorithm for such a task. If there are enough points use a kdtree-algorithm which has a lower computational complexity. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062049/4045774

Comment: The method suggested by @max9111 is much faster than what is in my answer.  You should un-accept my answer so I can delete it.  either max9111 should provide an answer or this question should be marked as a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062049/4045774).

Comment: No no I was specifically looking for an efficient implementation of all-to-all distances calculation in Cuda and retaining Top N as an exercise, while max9111 made a very good point suitable for production environment which I will investigate further into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be interested in an answer based on CUDA C++, so I'll provide one.  It should be straightforward to convert this kernel to an equivalent numba cuda jit kernel; the translation process is fairly mechanical.

An outline of the method I chose is as follows:

- assign one city per thread (the reference city for that thread)
- each thread traverses through all the cities computing the pairwise distance to its reference city
- as each distance is computed, it is checked to see if it is within the current "closest cities".  The approach here is to keep a running list for each thread.  As each thread computes a new distance, it checks to see if that distance is less than the current maximum distance in the running list.  If it is, the current maximum distance/city is replaced with the one just computed.
- The list of "closest cities" along with their distances is maintained in shared memory.
- At the completion of computing all distances, each thread then sorts and writes out the values in its shared buffer to global memory
- There are several "optimizations" to this basic plan.  One is that each warp reads 32 consecutive values at a time, and then uses a shuffle operation to pass the values around among threads, so as to reduce global memory traffic.

A single kernel call performs the entire operation for all cities.

The performance of this kernel will vary quite a bit depending on the GPU you are running it on.  For example on a tesla P100 it runs in about 0.5s.  On a Tesla K40 it takes ~6s.  On a Quadro K2000 it takes ~40s.

Here is a full test case on the Tesla P100:

```
$ cat t364.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

const int ncities = 200064;  // should be divisible by nTPB
const int nclosest = 32;     // maximum 48
const int nTPB = 128;        // should be multiple of 32
const float FLOAT_MAX = 999999.0f;


__device__ void init_shared(float *d, int n){
  int idx = threadIdx.x;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    d[idx] = FLOAT_MAX;
    idx += nTPB;}
}

__device__ int find_max(float *d, int n){
  int idx = threadIdx.x;
  int max = 0;
  float maxd = d[idx];
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    idx += nTPB;
    float next = d[idx];
    if (maxd < next){
      max = i;
      maxd = next;}}
  return max;
}

__device__ float compute_sqdist(float2 c1, float2 c2){
  return (c1.x - c2.x)*(c1.x - c2.x) + (c1.y - c2.y)*(c1.y - c2.y);
}

__device__ void sort_and_store_sqrt(int idx, float *closest_dist, int *closest_id, float *dist,  int *city, int n, int n_cities)
{
  for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
    int max = find_max(dist, n);
    closest_dist[idx + i*n_cities] = sqrtf(dist[max*nTPB+threadIdx.x]);
    closest_id[idx + i*n_cities] = city[max*nTPB+threadIdx.x];
    dist[max*nTPB+threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;}
};


__device__ void shuffle(int &city_id, float2 &next_city_xy, int my_warp_lane){

  int src_lane = (my_warp_lane+1)&31;
  city_id = __shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, city_id, src_lane);
  next_city_xy.x = __shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, next_city_xy.x, src_lane);
  next_city_xy.y = __shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, next_city_xy.y, src_lane);
}

__global__ void k(const float2 * __restrict__ cities, float * __restrict__ closest_dist, int * __restrict__ closest_id, const int n_cities){

  __shared__  float dist[nclosest*nTPB];
  __shared__  int   city[nclosest*nTPB];

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int my_warp_lane = (threadIdx.x & 31);
  init_shared(dist, nclosest);
  float2 my_city_xy = cities[idx];
  float last_max = FLOAT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_cities; i+=32){
    int city_id = i+my_warp_lane;
    float2 next_city_xy = cities[city_id];
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
      if (j > 0) shuffle(city_id, next_city_xy, my_warp_lane);
      if (idx != city_id){
        float my_dist = compute_sqdist(my_city_xy, next_city_xy);
        if (my_dist < last_max){
          int max = find_max(dist, nclosest);
          last_max = dist[max*nTPB+threadIdx.x];
          if (my_dist < last_max) {
            dist[max*nTPB+threadIdx.x] = my_dist;
            city[max*nTPB+threadIdx.x] = city_id;}}}}}
  sort_and_store_sqrt(idx, closest_dist, closest_id, dist, city, nclosest, n_cities);
}

void on_cpu(float2 *cities, float *dists, int *ids){
  thrust::host_vector<int> my_ids(ncities);
  thrust::host_vector<float> my_dists(ncities);
  for (int i = 0; i < ncities; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncities; j++){
      my_ids[j] = j;
      if (i != j) my_dists[j] = sqrtf((cities[i].x - cities[j].x)*(cities[i].x - cities[j].x) + (cities[i].y - cities[j].y)*(cities[i].y - cities[j].y));
      else my_dists[j] = FLOAT_MAX;}
    thrust::sort_by_key(my_dists.begin(), my_dists.end(), my_ids.begin());
    for (int j = 0; j < nclosest; j++){
      dists[i+j*ncities] = my_dists[j];
      ids[i+j*ncities] = my_ids[j];}
    }
}


int main(){

  float2 *h_cities, *d_cities;
  float *h_closest_dist, *d_closest_dist, *h_closest_dist_cpu;
  int *h_closest_id, *d_closest_id, *h_closest_id_cpu;

  cudaMalloc(&d_cities, ncities*sizeof(float2));
  cudaMalloc(&d_closest_dist, nclosest*ncities*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_closest_id, nclosest*ncities*sizeof(int));

  h_cities = new float2[ncities];
  h_closest_dist = new float[ncities*nclosest];
  h_closest_id = new int[ncities*nclosest];
  h_closest_dist_cpu = new float[ncities*nclosest];
  h_closest_id_cpu = new int[ncities*nclosest];

  for (int i = 0; i < ncities; i++){
    h_cities[i].x = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*10.0f;
    h_cities[i].y = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*10.0f;}

  cudaMemcpy(d_cities, h_cities, ncities*sizeof(float2), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  k<<<ncities/nTPB, nTPB>>>(d_cities, d_closest_dist, d_closest_id, ncities);
  cudaMemcpy(h_closest_dist, d_closest_dist, ncities*nclosest*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(h_closest_id, d_closest_id, ncities*nclosest*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < nclosest; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) std::cout << h_closest_id[j+i*ncities] << ","  << h_closest_dist[j+i*ncities] << "   ";
    std::cout << std::endl;}
  if (ncities < 5000){
    on_cpu(h_cities, h_closest_dist_cpu, h_closest_id_cpu);
    for (int i = 0; i < ncities*nclosest; i++)
      if (h_closest_id_cpu[i] != h_closest_id[i]) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << h_closest_id[i] << " should be: " << h_closest_id_cpu[i] << std::endl; return -1;}
    }
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t364 t364.cu
$ nvprof ./t364
==31871== NVPROF is profiling process 31871, command: ./t364
33581,0.00466936   116487,0.0163371   121419,0.0119542   138585,0.00741395   187892,0.0205568
56138,0.0106946   105637,0.0195111   175565,0.0132018   121719,0.0090809   198333,0.0269794
36458,0.014851   6942,0.0244329   67920,0.013367   140919,0.014739   91533,0.0348142
48152,0.0221216   146867,0.0250192   14656,0.020469   163149,0.0247639   162442,0.0354359
3681,0.0226946   127671,0.0265515   32841,0.0219539   109520,0.0359874   21346,0.0424094
20903,0.0313963   3075,0.0279635   79787,0.0220388   106161,0.0365807   24186,0.0453916
191226,0.0316818   4168,0.0297535   126726,0.0246147   154598,0.0374218   62106,0.0459001
185573,0.0349628   76270,0.030849   122878,0.0249695   124897,0.0447656   38124,0.0463704
71252,0.037517   18879,0.0350544   112410,0.0299296   102006,0.0462593   12361,0.0464608
172641,0.0399721   134288,0.035077   39252,0.031506   164570,0.0470057   81105,0.0502873
18960,0.0433545   53266,0.0360357   195467,0.0334281   36715,0.0470069   153375,0.0508115
163568,0.0442928   95544,0.0361058   151839,0.0398384   114041,0.0490263   8524,0.0511531
182326,0.047519   59919,0.0362906   90810,0.0408069   52013,0.0494515   16793,0.0525569
169860,0.048417   77412,0.036694   12065,0.0414496   137863,0.0494703   197500,0.0537481
40158,0.0492621   34592,0.0377113   54812,0.041594   58792,0.049532   70501,0.0541114
121444,0.0501154   102800,0.0414865   96238,0.0433548   34323,0.0531493   161527,0.0551868
118564,0.0509228   82832,0.0449587   167965,0.0439488   104475,0.0534779   66968,0.0572788
60136,0.0528873   88318,0.0455667   118562,0.0462537   129853,0.0535594   7544,0.0588875
95975,0.0587857   65792,0.0479467   124929,0.046828   116360,0.0537344   37341,0.0594454
62542,0.0592229   57399,0.0509665   186583,0.0470843   47571,0.0541045   81275,0.0596965
11499,0.0607943   28314,0.0512354   23730,0.0518801   176089,0.0543222   562,0.06527
131594,0.0611795   23120,0.0515408   25933,0.0547776   117474,0.0557752   194499,0.0657885
23959,0.0623019   137283,0.0533193   173000,0.0577509   157537,0.0566689   193091,0.0666895
5660,0.0629772   15498,0.0555821   161025,0.0596721   123148,0.0589929   147928,0.0672529
51033,0.063036   15456,0.0565314   145859,0.0601408   3012,0.0601779   107646,0.0687241
26790,0.0643055   99659,0.0576798   33153,0.0603556   48388,0.0617377   47566,0.0689055
178826,0.0655352   143209,0.058413   101960,0.0604994   22146,0.0620504   91118,0.0705487
32108,0.0672866   172089,0.058676   17885,0.0638383   137318,0.0624543   138223,0.0716578
38125,0.0678566   42847,0.0609811   10879,0.0681518   154360,0.0633921   96195,0.0723226
96583,0.0683073   169703,0.0621889   100839,0.0721133   28595,0.0661302   20422,0.0731882
98329,0.0683718   50432,0.0636618   84204,0.0733909   181919,0.066552   75375,0.0736715
75814,0.0694582   161714,0.0674298   89049,0.0749184   151275,0.0679411   37849,0.0739173
==31871== Profiling application: ./t364
==31871== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   95.66%  459.88ms         1  459.88ms  459.88ms  459.88ms  k(float2 const *, float*, int*, int)
                    4.30%  20.681ms         2  10.340ms  10.255ms  10.425ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                    0.04%  195.55us         1  195.55us  195.55us  195.55us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
      API calls:   58.18%  482.42ms         3  160.81ms  472.46us  470.80ms  cudaMemcpy
                   41.05%  340.38ms         3  113.46ms  322.83us  339.73ms  cudaMalloc
                    0.55%  4.5490ms       384  11.846us     339ns  503.79us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.16%  1.3131ms         4  328.27us  208.85us  513.66us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.05%  407.13us         4  101.78us  93.796us  118.27us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.01%  61.719us         1  61.719us  61.719us  61.719us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.00%  23.965us         4  5.9910us  3.9830us  8.9510us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  6.8440us         8     855ns     390ns  1.8150us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  3.7490us         3  1.2490us     339ns  2.1300us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.0260us         4     506ns     397ns     735ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
$
```

CUDA 10.0, Tesla P100, CentOS 7

The code includes the possibility for verification, but it verifies the results against a CPU-based naive code, which takes quite a bit longer.  So I've restricted verification to smaller test cases, eg. 4096 cities.

Here's a "translated" approximation of the above code using numba cuda.  It seems to run about 2x slower than the CUDA C++ version, which shouldn't really be the case. (One of the contributing factors seems to be the use of the `sqrt` function - it is having a significant performance impact in the numba code but no perf impact in the CUDA C++ code.  It may be using a double-precision realization under the hood in numba CUDA.)  Anyway it gives a reference for how it could be realized in numba:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import math
from numba import cuda,float32,int32

# number of cities, should be divisible by threadblock size
N = 200064
# number of "closest" cities
TN = 32
#number of threads per block
threadsperblock = 128
#shared memory size of each array in elements
smSize=TN*threadsperblock
@cuda.jit('int32(float32[:])',device=True)
def find_max(dist):
    idx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    mymax = 0
    maxd = dist[idx]
    for i in range(TN-1):
        idx += threadsperblock
        mynext = dist[idx]
        if maxd < mynext:
            mymax = i+1
            maxd = mynext
    return mymax

@cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def k(citiesx, citiesy, td, ti, nc):
    dist = cuda.shared.array(smSize, float32)
    city = cuda.shared.array(smSize, int32)
    idx = cuda.grid(1)
    tid = cuda.threadIdx.x
    wl = tid & 31
    my_city_x = citiesx[idx];
    my_city_y = citiesy[idx];
    last_max = 99999.0
    for i in range(TN):
        dist[tid+i*threadsperblock] = 99999.0
    for i in xrange(0,nc,32):
        city_id = i+wl
        next_city_x = citiesx[city_id]
        next_city_y = citiesy[city_id]
        for j in range(32):
            if j > 0:
                src_lane = (wl+1)&31
                city_id = cuda.shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, city_id, src_lane)
                next_city_x = cuda.shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, next_city_x, src_lane)
                next_city_y = cuda.shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, next_city_y, src_lane)
            if idx != city_id:
                my_dist = (next_city_x - my_city_x)*(next_city_x - my_city_x) + (next_city_y - my_city_y)*(next_city_y - my_city_y)
                if my_dist < last_max:
                    mymax = find_max(dist)
                    last_max = dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid]
                    if my_dist < last_max:
                        dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid] = my_dist
                        city[mymax*threadsperblock+tid] = city_id
    for i in range(TN):
        mymax = find_max(dist)
        td[idx+i*nc] = math.sqrt(dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid])
        ti[idx+i*nc] = city[mymax*threadsperblock+tid]
        dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid] = 0

#peform test
cx  = np.random.rand(N).astype(np.float32)
cy  = np.random.rand(N).astype(np.float32)

td = np.zeros(N*TN, dtype=np.float32)
ti = np.zeros(N*TN, dtype=np.int32)


d_cx = cuda.to_device(cx)
d_cy = cuda.to_device(cy)
d_td = cuda.device_array_like(td)
d_ti = cuda.device_array_like(ti)
k[N/threadsperblock, threadsperblock](d_cx, d_cy, d_td, d_ti, N)
d_td.copy_to_host(td)
d_ti.copy_to_host(ti)
for i in range(TN):
    for j in range(1):
        print(ti[i*N+j])
        print(td[i*N+j])
```

I haven't included validation in this numba cuda variant, so it may contain defects.

EDIT:  By switching the above code examples from 128 threads per block to 64 threads per block, the codes will run noticeably faster.  This is due to the increase in the theoretical and achieved occupancy that this allows, in light of the shared memory limiter to occupancy.

As pointed out in the comments by max9111, a better algorithm exists.  Here's a comparison (on a very slow GPU) between the above python code and the tree-based algorithm (borrowing from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062049/4045774)):

```
$ cat t27.py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import math
from numba import cuda,float32,int32
from scipy import spatial
import time

#Create some coordinates and indices
#It is assumed that the coordinates are unique (only one entry per hydrant)
ncities = 200064
Coords=np.random.rand(ncities*2).reshape(ncities,2)
Coords*=100
Indices=np.arange(ncities) #Indices
nnear = 33
def get_indices_of_nearest_neighbours(Coords,Indices):
  tree=spatial.cKDTree(Coords)
  #k=4 because the first entry is the nearest neighbour
  # of a point with itself
  res=tree.query(Coords, k=nnear)[1][:,1:]
  return Indices[res]

start = time.time()
a = get_indices_of_nearest_neighbours(Coords, Indices)
end = time.time()
print (a.shape[0],a.shape[1])
print
print(end -start)

# number of cities, should be divisible by threadblock size
N = ncities
# number of "closest" cities
TN = nnear - 1
#number of threads per block
threadsperblock = 64
#shared memory size of each array in elements
smSize=TN*threadsperblock
@cuda.jit('int32(float32[:])',device=True)
def find_max(dist):
    idx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    mymax = 0
    maxd = dist[idx]
    for i in range(TN-1):
        idx += threadsperblock
        mynext = dist[idx]
        if maxd < mynext:
            mymax = i+1
            maxd = mynext
    return mymax

@cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def k(citiesx, citiesy, td, ti, nc):
    dist = cuda.shared.array(smSize, float32)
    city = cuda.shared.array(smSize, int32)
    idx = cuda.grid(1)
    tid = cuda.threadIdx.x
    wl = tid & 31
    my_city_x = citiesx[idx];
    my_city_y = citiesy[idx];
    last_max = 99999.0
    for i in range(TN):
        dist[tid+i*threadsperblock] = 99999.0
    for i in xrange(0,nc,32):
        city_id = i+wl
        next_city_x = citiesx[city_id]
        next_city_y = citiesy[city_id]
        for j in range(32):
            if j > 0:
                src_lane = (wl+1)&31
                city_id = cuda.shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, city_id, src_lane)
                next_city_x = cuda.shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, next_city_x, src_lane)
                next_city_y = cuda.shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, next_city_y, src_lane)
            if idx != city_id:
                my_dist = (next_city_x - my_city_x)*(next_city_x - my_city_x) + (next_city_y - my_city_y)*(next_city_y - my_city_y)
                if my_dist < last_max:
                    mymax = find_max(dist)
                    last_max = dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid]
                    if my_dist < last_max:
                        dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid] = my_dist
                        city[mymax*threadsperblock+tid] = city_id
    for i in range(TN):
        mymax = find_max(dist)
        td[idx+i*nc] = math.sqrt(dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid])
        ti[idx+i*nc] = city[mymax*threadsperblock+tid]
        dist[mymax*threadsperblock+tid] = 0

#peform test
cx  = np.zeros(N).astype(np.float32)
cy  = np.zeros(N).astype(np.float32)
for i in range(N):
  cx[i] = Coords[i,0]
  cy[i] = Coords[i,1]
td = np.zeros(N*TN, dtype=np.float32)
ti = np.zeros(N*TN, dtype=np.int32)

start = time.time()
d_cx = cuda.to_device(cx)
d_cy = cuda.to_device(cy)
d_td = cuda.device_array_like(td)
d_ti = cuda.device_array_like(ti)
k[N/threadsperblock, threadsperblock](d_cx, d_cy, d_td, d_ti, N)
d_td.copy_to_host(td)
d_ti.copy_to_host(ti)
end = time.time()
print(a)
print
print(end - start)
print(np.flip(np.transpose(ti.reshape(nnear-1,ncities)), 1))
$ python t27.py
(200064, 32)

1.32144594193
[[177220  25281 159413 ..., 133366  45179  27508]
 [ 56956 163534  90723 ..., 135081  33025 167104]
 [ 88708  42958 162851 ..., 115964  77180  31684]
 ...,
 [186540  52500 124911 ..., 157102  83407  38152]
 [151053 144837  34487 ..., 171148  37887  12591]
 [ 13820 199968  88667 ...,   7241 172376  51969]]

44.1796119213
[[177220  25281 159413 ..., 133366  45179  27508]
 [ 56956 163534  90723 ..., 135081  33025 167104]
 [ 88708  42958 162851 ..., 115964  77180  31684]
 ...,
 [186540  52500 124911 ..., 157102  83407  38152]
 [151053 144837  34487 ..., 171148  37887  12591]
 [ 13820 199968  88667 ...,   7241 172376  51969]]
$
```

On this very slow Quadro K2000 GPU, the CPU/scipy-based kd-tree algorithm is much faster than this GPU implementation.  However, at ~1.3s, the scipy implementation is still a bit slower than the brute-force CUDA C++ code running on a Tesla P100, and faster GPUs exist today.  A possible explanation for this disparity is given [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26871/performance-of-kd-tree-vs-brute-force-nearest-neighbor-search-on-gpu).  As pointed out there, the brute force approach is easily parallelizable, whereas the kd-tree approach may be non-trivial to parallelize.   In any event, a faster solution yet might be [a GPU-based kd-tree implementation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10766-018-0571-0).

Comment: Thank you so much for this great solution Robert! Idea of fusing distances calculation and argsorting is really brilliant. Also keeping a running list of best distances is a huge cycles saver. I'm just start learning Cuda so your code is of immense help to me. I will rewrite your code in python and will report timings on my original input data and your input data, so that we will be able to compare C++ and python solutions.

Comment: One possible improvement over your approach which immediately comes into my head is, in situation when hardware is capable of more threads than there are cities in the list, to split calculation into 2,3 or more chunks to spin more concurrent threads, then at last stage to merge results of chunks belonging to same city (row). However 200k cities will pretty sure saturate most of current GPU hardware including Teslas )

Comment: The kernel occupancy is limited by its large shared memory use (32kbytes per threadblock). If you have more than ~5000 cities, it will "saturate" any current GPU, and the splitting won't help.